I was trying this generate image from the delle open ai api but I am getting an error
Code:
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null); // Initialize result as null
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState(
    "Search Bears with Paint Brushes the Starry Night, painted by Vincent Van Gogh.."
  );

  const apiKey = import.meta.env.VITE_Open_AI_Key;

  const generateImage = async () => {
    setPlaceholder(`Search ${prompt}..`);
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations",
        {
          prompt: prompt,
          n: 1,
          size: "512x512",
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        }
      );

      setLoading(false);
      if (response.data.data && response.data.data.length > 0) {
        setResult(response.data.data[0].url);
      } else {
        console.error("No image URL found in response data");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.error("Error generating image:", error);
    }
  };

  return (

    <div className=" m-auto bg-white grid grid-flow-row justify-evenly p-8 ">
      {loading ? (
        <>
          <h2 className="p-4">Generating.. Please Wait..</h2>
          <div className="p-4">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <h2 className="p-4">Generate an Image </h2>

          <textarea
            className="p-4 m-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg shadow-blue-400 overflow-hidden"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={(e) => setPrompt(e.target.value)}
            rows="10"
            cols="40"
          />
          <button onClick={generateImage} className="  bg-purple-600 h-8 w-150 p-2 rounded-lg text-white  ">Generate an Image</button>
          {result && (
            <img className="result-image" src={result} alt="result" />
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Error:
App.jsx:19 POST https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations 400 (Bad Request)

App.jsx:42 Error generating image:

1. *AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}*

generateImage@App.jsx:42Show 15 more frames

This is the error:
{
    "error": {
        "code": null,
        "message": "Not allowed to GET on /v1/images/generations. (HINT: Perhaps you meant to use a different HTTP method?)",
        "param": null,
        "type": "invalid_request_error"
    }
}

This is the api response, I am using post method but still getting this.

400 error code say that rquest not is valid for endpoint, seek the documentation, you need send model field in your request:
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -d '{
    "model": "dall-e-3",
    "prompt": "A cute baby sea otter",
    "n": 1,
    "size": "1024x1024"
  }'


still getting same error . i am not able to solve this error . i tried many times but still getting same problem.
